# How can I personalize the enum errors from a Pallet that isn't in my workspace?

Tags: pallet, parachain, parachain-system

I'm trying to modify the enum errors that the `CumulusParachainSystem` pallet has, without having to import the pallet to my workspace.

It would be possible to add new errors as well, if so how?

Thanks in advance for any help, or documentation/material. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not change the `Error` from an external pallet.

I don't really know why you would like to do this. In your own pallet you can create your own `Error` type an return this.